# Is there an annotation to register a package of classes with JAXB?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

My understanding is that [JAXB must be aware of all the classes it might need to marshal or unmarshal](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/xml/bind/JAXBContext.html#newInstance%28java.lang.Class...%29). The [@XmlSeeAlso](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlSeeAlso.html) annotation can be used to make JAXB aware of classes it cannot detect for itself automatically, like so:

```
@XmlSeeAlso({Dog.class,Cat.class,Mouse.class})
```

Is there an annotation I can use to specify a package rather than list each individual class? If the classes above were in the package `com.zoo.animals`, I'd want to do:

```
@XmlSeeAlso("com.zoo.animals")
```

---

#### Additional information

1. The classes I want JAXB to be aware of are auto-generated by a proprietary tool.
2. There are hundreds of classes in this package.
3. The classes are not annotated with any JAXB annotations but in theory they could be if it was absolutely necessary.
4. There is no `package-info` or `jaxb.properties` file or such things to aid JAXB in discovering these classes. Again it's not unfeasible to generate such files if it were crucial.
5. There is no factory object that knows of all the classes.
6. [I believe what I want to achieve can be done in code](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/xml/bind/JAXBContext.html) using `JAXBContext.newInstance( "com.acme.foo:com.acme.bar")` but currently I don't interact with this object and didn't particularly want to if there was an equivalent annotation.

Answer (score 2):

When you create a `JAXBContext` on one or more package names JAXB will look in those packages for a `jaxb.index` file or `ObjectFactory` to determine the classes to create the `JAXBContext` on.  JAXB itself doesn't do any package scanning.

You can also create a `JAXBContext` on an array of classes.  You could leverage your own package scanner to come up with this array.

You mention you don't interact with `JAXBContext` directly.  Depending on your environment there are ways to handle this.  In JAX-RS for example you could use a `ContextResolver` to insert this logic.